# how to use curl or wget to download a text file off a website?

Tags: download, curl

i am trying to access eoddata.com to download a list of stock prices at the end of everyday without having to do it myself manually.

the full url i am trying to access would be something like:
http://eoddata.com/data/filedownload.aspx?e=AMEX&sd=20160603&ed=20160603&d=9&k=ejv5n7btwb&o=d&ea=1&p=0

I have tried doing a  curl request:

When using curl

```
curl username:password@www.eoddata.com/data/filedownload.aspx?e=AMEX&sd=20160602&ed=20160602&d=9&k=mbywemcptq&o=d&ea=1&p=0
```

the return is:

```
[1] 5179
[2] 5180
[3] 5181
[4] 5182
[5] 5183
[6] 5184
[7] 5185
[2]   Done                    sd=20160602
[3]   Done                    ed=20160602
[4]   Done                    d=9
[5]   Done                    k=mbywemcptq
[6]-  Done                    o=d
[7]+  Done                    ea=1
```

with no file being downloaded. I am not sure what this means.
will it not work because the url doesnt end in .txt or .zip?

i have tried adding http:// before the url and it says http host not found.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the site needs a password?

Comment: Your shell is treating the & special.  (I suspect you're in Unix, and it is backgrounding the various pieces, and showing you PIDs.)  Try simply surrounding your whole URL (everything after the word "curl") with quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote the URL, as & has special meanings in the shell (it sends the command preceding it to the background).

```
curl -O "http://username:password@www.eoddata.com/data/filedownload.aspx?e=AMEX&sd=20160602&ed=20160602&d=9&k=mbywemcptq&o=d&ea=1&p=0"
```

Comment: I have tried it with this addition just as youve alluded to.  now a file downloads with the exact name (to be expected) yet under the curl request diagnostics, % Total ,% received, speed upload ... etc are all 0 and the file is empty.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with the server and not curl. Perhaps your session has expired.